# prevent pwa from caching dynamic content on a file

Tags: progressive-web-apps

i'm currently playing with PWA
i still don't know how do i prevent pwa to cache a "dynamic content" on my page.

In this case, i'm not using any API or any SPA app. 
I'm using normal PHP site, which all the data is rendered with the page.

Example:
lets say i'm caching '/' file.
So when my index page already fill with the data that rendered with the page. It will always stay the same, since it's also cached.

hope it also help others!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you've provided little info of your architecture. So, I can only assume that you use [Cache Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) and [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) to serve cached pages. If my guess is right, you might use AJAX to load dynamic content. The service worker is a middleman between the browser and network. So, it works with the Request/Response pair of HTTP. It doesn't care what is returned from the server, it might be any valid HTTP response. Thus, there is no way to say *hey, cache this part of HTML, but don't cache that part*.

Comment: hello Dmitry thanks for your response. I'm asking generally is it even possible if we're not using any ajax, just normal backend-frontend app (data already rendered with the page from backend)